# How can I improve my use of Android SharedPreference?

Tags: java, android, dialog, sharedpreferences

I want to run another application whose package name is obtained from EditText in AlertDialog. My problem is that I want to display Dialog only when PackageName has not been specified in SharedPreference or when the application is not available.

Here is my code:

```
public static final String mypref="mypref";
public static final String packagename="text";
private SharedPreferences pref;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    gpref();
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1)
                    {
                        // TODO: Implement this method
                        String s=pref.getString(packagename);
                        if(s!=""){
                            Intent i=getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(s);
                            if(i!=null){
                                startActivity(i);
                            } else{ sd();}
                        } else{
                            sd();
                        }
                    }
            });
}
public void sd(){
    final EditText et=new EditText(this);
    AlertDialog ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    ad.setView(et); ad.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
            "Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface p1, int p2)
                        {
                            // TODO: Implement this method
                            String s=et.getText().toString();
                            spref(s);
                        }
                });
}
public void gpref(){
    pref=getSharedPreferences(mypref,MODE_PRIVATE);
}
public void spref(String s){
    gpref();
    SharedPreferences.Editor spedit=pref.edit();
    spedit.putString(packagename,s); spedit.apply();
}
```

but I did not find a way to ensure packagename at SharedPreference since packagename has not been set. Would anyone give me some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [official reference about getString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

When specific preference does not set, the getString method would be return default value.
you could check against this default value.For example:

```
String s=pref.getString(packagename,"Default");
if(!s.equals("Default")){
//Do something
}
```